# Как сделать движение объекта по направлению курсора?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть игрок который выпускает пули, и я пытался сделать так, чтоб он стрелял по направлению курсора, чтоб лучше попадать во врагов, но столкнулся с проблемой, что чем дальше я отходил от начала карты (~644, 720), тем выше начинали лететь пули, и они уже не летят по направлению мышки, а лишь вверх в какую-то точку.

```py
if mkeys[0] and not self.attack_pressed:
    self.last_shoot = coltdown
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Находим точки начала и конца атаки
    x_start, y_start = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery
    x_end, y_end = mouse_pos[0], mouse_pos[1]

    # Добавляем смещение между игроком и точкой начала атаки
    x_offset, y_offset = self.rect.centerx - (map_width / 2), self.rect.centery - (map_height / 2)
    x_start -= x_offset
    y_start -= y_offset
    x_end -= x_offset
    y_end -= y_offset

    # Нормализуем вектор направления атаки
    dx, dy = x_end - x_start, y_end - y_start
    length = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
    dx, dy = dx / length, dy / length

    # Учесть размеры карты
    dx *= map_width / max(map_width, map_height)
    dy *= map_height / max(map_width, map_height)

    atack = Atack(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, (dx, dy))
    sprites.add(atack)

    self.attack_pressed = True
```

Код выпуска пуль, так сказать.

```
# атака
class Atack(Item):
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        super().__init__(ATACK_HITBOX, WHITE)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(ATACK_HITBOX)
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = 15
        self.lifetime = 100 # время жизни атаки в кадрах
        self.attack_pressed = False
        self.coltdown = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # движение атаки
    def move(self):
        # перемещаем атаку вдоль вектора направления с определенной скоростью
        dx = self.direction[0] * self.speed
        dy = self.direction[1] * self.speed
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
#другой код.
```

Код некой пули.

> Пытался попросить помощи у нейросети, но ничего не помогло, честно говоря понятия не имею что мне нужно сделать.
>
> > Я использую библиотеку PyTMX для импрорта карты! Может это имеет значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому помогу:
Всё это время я допускал огромную ошибку - я вычислял координаты мыши используя координаты игрока, а так как карта большая, то и координаты были больше координат расположения мыши, из-за этого пули стреляли высоко вверх а не по направлению мыши. Решение оказалось проще, чем я думал.
Нужно было считывать координаты мыши и использовать при этом координаты монитора, а не карты, тогда всё заработало.

```
# выглядит это так:
screen_size = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

# Получаем координаты мыши относительно экрана
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

# Вычисляем координаты мыши относительно центра экрана
mouse_x = mouse_pos[0] - screen_size[0] // 2 + self.rect.centerx
mouse_y = mouse_pos[1] - screen_size[1] // 2 + self.rect.centery

# Вычисляем направление
angle = np.arctan2(mouse_y - self.rect.centery, mouse_x - self.rect.centerx)
dx = np.cos(angle)
dy = np.sin(angle)
self.direction = (dx, dy)

# движение атаки
def move(self):
    # перемещаем атаку
    self.rect.x += self.speed * self.direction[0]
    elf.rect.y += self.speed * self.direction[1]
```

Вот так, решение оказалось довольно проще, чем я думал! :)